# Microsoft Configuration Manager Issue

Tags: windows, configuration, sql, sccm, configuration-management

I cannot join the primary site to an existing hierarchy while installing Microsoft Configuration Manager. SQL and the SCCM Server are connected. Am I doing something wrong?

[Problem with Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asxRy.png)

Comment: Is there any more error information in ConfigMgrSetupWizard.log